# Hard coded filter in PowerBi measure

Tags: powerbi

I have a measure (Users_1) that calculates number of rows between specific dates that have the parameter is_sql = 0.
This measure is used in a table alongside with other measures.

I have 5 more filters on the page that that should affect this specific measure and so I can not use All(users).
One of the filters on this page is "is_sql". And when is_sql = 1 every measure except for measure (Users_1) should change to correspondig value. Measure (Users_1) shold stay the same.

Now when I chose is_sql = 1 the measure (Users_1) is blank.

```
Users_1 = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS( 'users' ), 
    FILTER(
        KEEPFILTERS('users'),
        'users'[date (days)] <= MAX( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        &&'users'[date (days)] >= MIN( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        &&'users'[is_SQL] = 0

    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to avoid using KEEPFILTERS on any filters you want to allow to look outside of the filter context:

```
Users_1 = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS( 'users' ), 
    'users'[date (days)] <= MAX( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
    'users'[date (days)] >= MIN( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
    'users'[is_SQL] = 0
)
```

Comment: This suggestion still does not give me the desired output. When I toggle the filter is_sql =1, the measure shows blank value